# How to solve these kind of Modular Arithmetics situations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, computer-science

Helloo...
Im kinda dumb in Discrete Mathematics since I just started studying it currently and I'm trying to figure out **studying material** to get remainders from operations like $11^{14^{4578369}}\pmod {41}$ or $11^{3928454} \pmod {3293}$. Can someone gimme hints or even the path to follow for their solutions?

I've tried using fermat's little theorem but I couldn't solve them anyway , cuz in the first case it's kinda power from power situation and the other one the mod isn't prime.

**Note: Here's a transcription of the exercises that uses these operations that im talking about. Thanks, though.**

> Considering $a=11^{3928454}$, $b=3293$ and $x$ as the
> remainder from division of $a$ by $b$. Which is the addition of all
> $x$ digits?  
>  a. 1
>  b. 2
>  c. 4
>  d. 3
>  Considering
> $a=11^{14^{4578369}}$ and $b=41$. Which is the remainder from division
> of $a$ by $b$.
>  a.40
>  b.38
>  c.37
>  d.39

**EXTRA NOTE: I don't want the correct alternatives, I only want to figure out how to use Fermat's Little theorem in these situations !!!!**

Comment: You could use the upgraded version of Fermat's Little Theorem known as [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). There are other approaches, though.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: Hey, u mean to use Euler's theorem in the (mod 3293) case which has 37 and 89 as its coprimes?? I thought phi only gives divisors, how do I get the remainders then?  What about power of power case?

Comment: About chinese remainder I just have gave a peek in a pdf but it was kinda bad explained, u know any good article with good examples?

Comment: I'm not sure you've totally understood the statement of Euler's Theorem. Here, since $11$ and $3293$ are coprime, Euler's Theorem applies to tell us that $11^{\varphi(b)} \equiv 1 \pmod{b}$. Letting $a = \varphi(b) q + r$ with $0 \leq r < \varphi(b)$, we therefore get $11^a = 11^{\varphi(b) q + r} = (11^{\varphi(b)})^q 11^r \equiv 1^q 11^r = 11^r \pmod{b}$, so if you can find the remainder of $a$ when divided by $\varphi(b)$, you'll have a simpler problem.

Notice that $\varphi(3293) = \varphi(37 \cdot 89) = \varphi(37) \cdot \varphi(89) = 36 \cdot 88 = 3168$.

Comment: I know very much of the theory but I can't abstract without seeing exercises examples. That's where my difficult is you know, even with my researches I didn't find exercises alike them.

Comment: Hey, where did $a=φ(b)q+r$ come from?

Comment: $q$ and $r$ come from dividing $a$ by $\varphi(b)$ with remainder.

Comment: I used brilliant.org's quizzes and wikis to learn the basics of it. You can try it as well.

Comment: @Rubenszinho Welcome to Math SE. I believe you'll find at least a few of the answers in [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/602049), as well as in some of its many linked posts, to be helpful.